# Creating simple table with PHP PDF functions

Tags: php, pdf-generation

Does anyone know how to use the PHP PDF library to create a table? I think I need to know how to use the `PDF_add_table_cell` and `PDF_fit_table` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those functions are from PDFLib. There's better examples/more complete documentation at the PDFlib site here: http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/ (scroll down to "PDFLib Manuals") and complete examples here: http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/tables/

Answer (score -1):

I use [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com)  and i generate html table then rendering with mpdf.